# latexdiff-vc with --only-changes option

Tags: latexdiff

I am trying to run

`latexdiff-vc --pdf --only-changes -r [git revision SHA number] main.tex`

but I receive the error:

```
Cannot combine graphics markup with float styles defining \DIFaddbeginFL in terms of \DIFaddbegin. 
Use --graphics-markup=none option or choose a different float style. at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexdiff line 1302.
```

What is going wrong?

Could it be that I don't have the package zref properly installed? If this is the case, I followed these steps here `https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/zref/zref.pdf` , but still no changes on the error above. Is there a way to independently check if there is something wrong with the zref installation?

Just to be clear, I have no issues when I call `latexdiff-vc` without the `--only-changes` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--only-changes` is not compatible with graphics markup. You have to specify the option `--graphics-markup=none` (as also hinted by the error message).
In releases of latexdiff-vc 1.3.2 and higher this is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works (I'm using latexdiff-vc version 1.3.0). I was worried about the zref package installation and I did not interpreted that `--graphics-markup` was a latexdiff-vc option.